# ARKit – Zoom into object with "UIPinchGestureRecognizer"

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

I want to zoom into the object. The position where I'm zooming should get centered.

The way it is:
1. I zoom.
2. The object scale is modified.
3. The point where I zoomed isn't centered since the object is only scaled and not transformed and stays at the same position.

Any suggestions?

I tried to solve it this way: get the point where the gesture is taken place then apply the scale to this point and then use the points in a way to get a transform vector to apply that to the `SCNNode`, but it didn't work. Below is one of the failures:

```
@objc fileprivate func handlePinch(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let terrain = terrain else {
        return
    }
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        startScale = terrain.scale.x
    }
    guard let startScale = startScale else {
        return
    }

    let identity = CGAffineTransform.identity

    // zoom point and screen center
    let point = gesture.location(in: self.sceneView)

    // 1. scale
    let newScale: Float = startScale * Float(gesture.scale)
    terrain.scale = SCNVector3(newScale, newScale, newScale)
    if gesture.state == .ended {
        self.startScale = nil
    }

    let pointScaled = point.applying(identity.scaledBy(x: gesture.scale, y:             gesture.scale)) 

    let vector: SCNVector3 = SCNVector3Make(Float(pointScaled.x - point.x), Float(pointScaled.y - point.y), 1)
    terrain.position += vector
}
```

Comment: Are you zooming or scaling?  Because if you want to zoom, I would move the camera closer to the object (or in ARKits case, the object closer to the camera)  I wouldnt even bother with scaling.